# React setState to update object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code

```
axios
            .get("some.url")
            .then(res => {
                console.log(...res.data);
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true, 
                    assignmentData: {...res.data}
                });
                console.log(this.assignmentData) //this returns undefined
            })
```

which fetches some data from the back-end and saves it to a state variable. The data sent from the server is in the following format
`[{id:1, title:"abc"},{id:2,title:"bcd"}]`. However, the value of `assignmentData` is not updated with the setState as the following `console.log` returns undefined.

How can I update the `assignmentData` state with the data received from the server?

Comment: setState is an asynchronous function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly: `assignmentData` will be added to the state `this.state.assignmentData`

and secondly, `this.setState(..)` is asynchronous.

If you want to view the data after it is set, you can do something like this:

```
this.setState({
  isLoaded: true, 
  assignmentData: {...res.data}
}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.assignmentData)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to access a value pertaining to the object that doesn't exist. It exists in `state`. Therefore you access as follows:

```
this.state.assignmentData
```

To access the value in your console log, supply your setState with a callback since it's async:

```
this.setState({
  isLoaded: true,
  assignmentData: { ...res.data },
}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.assignmentData);
});
```

Comment: that will still be wrong for the specific `console.log` since `setState` is async

Answer (score 2):

log date in asynchronous callback of setState because setState is asynchronous

```
axios
            .get("some.url")
            .then(res => {
                console.log(...res.data);
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true, 
                    assignmentData: {...res.data}
                },() => console.log(this.state.assignmentData)  );
            })
```

Comment: `this.assignmentData` will never be set by this code. It should be `this.state.assignmentData`

Answer (score 0):

Console in callback of setState because it's asynchronous

```
    axios
    .get("some.url")
    .then(res => {
        console.log(...res.data);
        this.setState({
            isLoaded: true, 
            assignmentData: {...res.data}
        },()=>console.log(this.state.assignmentData));
    })
```

or console inside `render()` you will get updated state.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
axios.get("some.url")
     .then(async(res) => {
       console.log(...res.data);
       await this.setState({
         isLoaded: true, 
         assignmentData: {...res.data}
       });
       console.log(this.assignmentData);
});
```